# Google Cloud Endpoints keeps reseting to <none>

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-endpoints, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an app running in a kubernetes engine cluster and communicating to elasticsearch in compute engine. The way they communicate is set up like this: a service in kubernetes engine that points to an endpoints and this enpoints has the ip and port of elasticsearch in compute engine. The problem is, the enpoints keeps on reseting to  every after around 5 or more hours. So I have to re-apply the endpoints configuration every now and then. Been trying to find out what causes it to reset to . So far my effort has been futile. Any help and thoughts are greatly appreciated...

Comment: Are there perhaps logs in Stackdriver related to your endpoints configuration that we can look at to see what might be happening at the time of the reset?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think I already solved this. The service that is using the endpoint did not explicitly declare its clusterIP. When I added that... The endpoints is now working 24/7.

Comment: Thanks for posting the comment.  Might I suggest that you post an answer to your own question so that others who come in the future might learn from your answer?  It will also flag question as having been resolved in case someone else may stop by thinking they can assist.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by explicitly declaring the clusterIP of the service that is pointing to this endpoint.